# Need help for developing facebook app

Tags: python, django, facebook

I am trying to develop a facebook app using django.

The problem I am facing is how to use facebook api and get user friend list.

**view.py**

```
def canvas(request):
    # Get the User object 
    user, created = FacebookUser.objects.get_or_create(id = request.facebook.uid)
    return direct_to_template(request, 'canvas.fbml', extra_context={'fbuser': user,})
```

so it's working fine for me. I am getting user info in my page.

```
Welcome,<fb:name uid="{{ fbuser.id }}" firstnameonly="true" useyou="false" />!
```

this is canvas.fbml

Help needed.

Thanks.

Comment: What help is needed?  What doesn't work?  What's broken?  What error are you getting?  What can't you do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes when loading up the userID etc.

Failing that it would appear to be either of the following
- Output error from python. The HTML / FBML output should be as follows

- Double  check the attributes you are adding are correct. Case sensitive.
- Are you loading you the correct authentication info (Keys) in this file? I'm assuming as its on the canvas its all ok. Test hte FBML in the FBML console.